# Use shell wildcard OR with diskutil

Tags: terminal, diskutil

I have the following terminal command, which matches volumes called A001R45R, A123R45R, etc.

```
diskutil eraseVolume HFS+ FreshMag /Volumes/*R45R
```

But I also want it to match volumes called B001R4G5, B150R4G5, etc.  How can I use the OR expression in the wildcard?  I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
$ diskutil eraseVolume HFS+ FreshMag /Volumes/{*R45R,*R4G5}
The third parameter does not appear to be "bootable" or "nonbootable"
$ diskutil eraseVolume HFS+ FreshMag /Volumes/"{*R45R,*R4G5}"
Unable to find disk for /Volumes/{*R45R,*R4G5}
```

I'm using bash.

Comment: Do You have other volumes which contains `R4` in the middle of their name? If not You can use: `diskutil eraseVolume HFS+ FreshMag /Volumes/*R4*`

Comment: Your shell is doing the expansion here - you should clarify which shell you're using.

Comment: Mateusz, that won't work for me.  These were just two examples, but I have others that don't share characters. I'm using bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself.  Apparently the bash version in OS X supports square brackets, but not curly brackets.  Weird.  It's bash 3.2.53.  This command works:

```
diskutil eraseVolume HFS+ FreshMag /Volumes/*[R45R,R4G5]
```

However, in this particular case, it's actually better to use a more specific command like this:

```
diskutil eraseVolume HFS+ FreshMag /Volumes/[A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][R,L]???
```

It should be noted that if more than one volume matches this wildcard, the command will fail, because the wildcard expands to both filenames.